# Implementation of Integrator in PID control

Tags: pid-controller

I have a doubt in implementing PID control. I referred many documents and video tutorials regarding this. But I am quite confused regarding the implementation of integrator in PID control. I could see that there are two ways used for implementing the integrator.

1. `IntegralError = IntegralError + error;`
2. `pid->integrator = pid->integrator + 0.5f * pid->Ki * pid->T * (error + pid->prevError);`

I found this code (2nd method) above from this [example](https://github.com/pms67/PID/blob/master/PID.c)

The first method is straight forward. I can understand it. But the second method is not clear to me. What is the role of `pid->prevError?` How integration is achieved here? Which of the above methods are more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

The first equation does not include the sample time, so it will have to be included elsewhere.

Aside from the difference in code (or pseudo-code) flavour, the second one explicitly includes the sample time and uses the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) (a rudimentary way of getting better integration accuracy).

There are better ways again (Simpson's Rule, for example).

The second method could be better than the first if the sample time is such that the PV changes significantly between samples. A relatively slow sample rate often means other issues arise.